# Jquery Listen for click event and class change

Tags: jquery, events, click, toggle

I'm trying to listen for the click/toggle event (class change) when a user clicks on the a button created using an a tag:

```
<a href="#" class="ccc-toggle-shadow"></a>
```

The process goes like this:

If the user clicks on the link, a class, toggled, is added to the  tag, the button changes color to red:

```
<a href="#" class="ccc-toggle-shadow toggled"></a>
```

and If the user clicks on the link again, the class, toggled, is removed, the button changes color to green:

```
<a href="#" class="ccc-toggle-shadow"></a>
```

Here is what I have so far to listen to the changes:

So basically when a user clicks on the button, the toggle class is added to the button class automatically. I want to capture the event when the new class has been added. Once it sees that the button has the new class, toggled, do something.

```
var a = $("a.ccc-toggle-shadow");  

a.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var b = $(this);

    if (b.hasClass('toggled')) {
        console.log('activated');  //test in console
    } else {
        console.log('deactivated'); // test in console
    }
    return false;
});
```

I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone please assist me?

Comment: So what is `b`, you have `a` ?

Comment: The code has been edited.

Comment: @user3442787: Have you tried below shared answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** instead:

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
>   matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the switch argument.

```
$("a.ccc-toggle-shadow").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7h6KR/)**

Answer (score 0):

use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to add/remove one or more classes to html elements:

```
$("a.ccc-toggle-shadow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RxtG9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Since I was using a plugin, I had to wait for the plugin to be loaded in order to listen to the event. I had to use jQuery(window).load(function(){});